# Mongoose cast error - embedded sub document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Take a look at the following schema design:

```
var message = new Schema({
  receivers: [User],
  message: String,
  owner: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

var user = new Schema({
  name: String,
  photo: String
});

var inbox = new Schema({
  messages: [Message],
  owner: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
  },
  sequence: Number
});
```

When I try to create a new message with:

```
var newMessage = {
  receivers: ['<id1>', '<id2>'],
  message: 'Hello world',
  owner: '<userId>'
}

Inbox.findOneAndUpdate({
  owner: '<userId>'
}, {
  $push: {
    messages: newMessage
  },
  $set: {
    sequence: '<sequence>'
  }
}, {
  upsert: true
}, callback);
```

It returns the following error:

```
MongooseError.CastError "Cast to undefined failed for value [object Object] at path "messages""
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `receivers` field for the message object is expecting an array of objects with the `User` schema, not an array of `ObjectId's` hexadecimal string representation. Thus you need to replace the `receivers` array with the actual objects represented by the ids, something like

```
var newMessage = {
    receivers: ['<id1>', '<id2>'],
    message: 'Hello world',
    owner: '<userId>'
};

Users.find({ "_id": {"$in": newMessage.receivers} }, function (err, users){
    // handle error
    if (err) throw err;

    // do the update
    newMessage.receivers = users;
    Inbox.findOneAndUpdate(
        { owner: '<userId>'}, 
        {  
            $push: { messages: newMessage  },
            $set: { sequence: '<sequence>' }
        }, 
        { upsert: true}, callback
    );
});
```